# MySQL BLOB or VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, json, base64, blob, varchar

I have to store a whole form data at about 300 000 times. Pls do not ask why. ;)

So, I have a JSON serialized form data with about 20-30 simple fields.

What do you think, which is more efficient? May I have to store this JSON base64 encoded in a VARCHAR or gzcompressed in a BLOB?

I know the difference between VARCHAR and BLOB, but the base64 quite bigger  than a gzcompressed json. FYI: The bas64 encoded form is about 2.3K while the same data gzcompressed is only 420 bytes.

It isnt neccessary to search inside these forms, just store them.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL actually has a [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) data type.

Comment: Yeah, It is could be good. Thanks for your suggestion.
But what about the size of the database? It is not a few but thousend of records. The advantages of the JSON field type is the optimized storage, but the stored size is bigger I think. Not you?

Comment: Thousands of records? If you're talking about thousands of records it's probably not going to be a problem. But of course depends on how huge your JSON documents are. If you have 500 Mio. 0.5kB JSON documents then your database is going to be 250GB. There probably isn't a huge difference between storing JSON as JSON or BLOB depending on the engine you're using you may also employ compression to reduce the storage requirements. We have about 350 Mio. JSON documents and the total DB size is around 80GB (but of course, our JSON documents are rather small about 100-200 bytes each).

Comment: Sorry, I mean hundred-thousands of records. More precisely it is about 350 thousands. But indeed it is about less than 350 Mio. :)